# DPI of app icon and launch images in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, iphone-x, ios12, iphone-xs-max

I am building my first iphone app. What should be the dpi of my .png images for the app icon and launch images? Does apple accept svgs?  The other answers I found on SO are from 2014 and only cover up to iPhone 6s.

Answer (score 0):

The dpi of your images doesn't matter. The resolution is what matters.
Apple does not accept SVGs unfortunately.